# Unity, delegate can't achieve transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, delegates

I have two classes added like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBvln.png)

MazeGenerator has delegate and event:

```
public delegate void MazeReadyAction();
public static event MazeReadyAction OnMazeReady;
```

MazeDirectives has such code:

```
void Awake()
{
    MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady += StartDirectives;   
}

void StartDirectives()
{

    mazeCoinPositions = MazeGenerator.instance.GetRandomFloorPositions(coinsToFind);

    for (int i = 0; i < mazeCoinPositions.Count; i++)
    {
        MazeCoin mazeCoin = Instantiate(mazeCoinPrefab, mazeCoinPositions[i], Quaternion.identity) as MazeCoin;
        mazeCoin.transform.SetParent(transform);
    }
}
```

which basically creates coins in a maze and set **transform as their parent**. This function is added to the delegate which is executed in MazeGenerator:

```
void Start()
{
    if (OnMazeReady != null)
    {
        OnMazeReady();
    }  
}
```

After player dies I change the scene Game to Menu scene like this:

```
public void LoadByIndex(int sceneIndex)
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex);
}
```

where index comes from Build Settings.
The problem is that after the Player clicks Start button in the menu, which basically changes the Scene to Game again, after death the

```
  mazeCoin.transform.SetParent(transform);
```

can not achieve transform (SetParent(**transform**)) and I get
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'MazeDirectives' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
I am curious why the OnMazeReady delegate is executed correctly from the first time but not again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add and remove listeners correctly.
For example, in OnEnable() add listeners and in OnDisable() remove them like below:

You can use UnityEvent and UnityAction in unity as well.

```
private void OnEnable(){
       MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady += StartDirectives;   
}
private void OnDisable(){
       MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady -= StartDirectives;   
}
```